# Video Streaming recommendations

Tags: video, streaming

We plan on setting up about 10 webinars and I'd like to ask for recommendations on how to set it up. I'm thinking LiveStream with about 2-3 cameras. Here's the question - would it be better to have 3 feeds into 3 streams or just run the 3 cams via a video mixer and then feed this to LiveStream - does anybody have any experience with this? What would be the best video mixer if ever. This is on a Windows set-up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 cams via a video mixer into a single Livestream - you do not want your users to get confused and switch around, missing out on portions of the webinar.

Any common video mixer would be fine, we used to video events using a single Sony 5-input-1-output selector with 4 cameras connected via video, but 1 audio source (which can be from multiple audio source into a single sound mixer) split into all 4 inputs (so as to avoid audio suddenly sounding different as we switch camviews), and the output connects to a USB capture device.

Simple, but effective. ;) KISS policy at work here.

Comment: @scoopdreams what video mixer would you recommend and what streaming service?

Comment: @pageman - streaming service, I've been quite fascinated with USTREAM, after hearing they actually have an iPhone app for viewing - that would help alot with getting audience to your webinar.

Comment: @pageman - As to the video mixer, do you need fancy features, or will normal cuts do for you? For a webinar, where the content and audio delivery is more important, I suggest you get a video mixer that supports cross-fades at the very least for soothing transitions. You can try Edirol's video mixers - quite popular and affordable for small establishments.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with LiveStream, but [USTREAM](http://www.ustream.tv/) is the same idea and was quick and painless to set up. Good quality as well. I'd go with 3 separate streams so users don't get distracted and to make things easier.

Answer (score 1):

Video Mixer all the way!

It depends on the topics, but I can't imagine people liking to have 3 or 4 windows/tabs open and then saying to go here, go there e.t.c.

If I was a viewer, I would hate it!